# What would be better in Java for networking? UDP or TCP?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp, packets

What should be used for a mmo game in java. UDP or TCP? And why? TCP is a point-to-point relationship and carries every packet through while UDP has no point-to-point relationship and can drop off packets resulting in lag. Which one is the better one to use in this scenario?

Comment: Lag is not just a result of dropped UDP datagrams.  TCP will give lag over a noisy connection as well.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends not on the language, but on the requirements of the game.

If your game can cope with status updates from players (or the server) either going missing, or arriving out of order, then UDP should be fine.

If you need real-time response with minimal latency (and the above issues are solved) then you should also UDP.

Otherwise, you should use TCP.

Comment: There's a realtime layer on top of UDP that's used for certain types of videoconferencing systems, which might be suitable *provided it is OK to drop late/missing information*.

Comment: @Donal - you mean RTP? It's unnecessarily complicated for most other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if it's Java or not,  TCP and UDP have the same advantages and drawbacks that are independent of the language.

But more often than not it boils down to one basic design question: when a packet is dropped, what should happen?

1. Pretend it never happened. This is UDP territory.
2. Wait until the packet is resent. This is where TCP should be used.

Neither approach is right or wrong in itself, both will cause problems in your game, but this is the question you should answer first.

Comment: UDP can reorder packets too, but it does apply integrity checking (one of the reasons for dropping a packet is if it becomes corrupt).

Comment: @Donal - many systems don't correctly generate UDP checksums, and send the default value of '0' to indicate it.

Comment: @Donal Fellows True, the main question should be more general, i.e. what to do when packets don't arrive in order or at all. Of course there are other important aspects to consider, like firewalls and proxies, but as a starting point, this will probably do.

Comment: @Alnitak: Augh! Facepalm time. What's the point of having an integrity guarantee (even a cheapo one like a checksum) if you don't use it?!

Comment: @biziclop: The only thing that stands the slightest chance of getting out everywhere is plain old HTTP. Probably via a badly mismanaged and aggressive proxy that's been implemented badly too. (I've been to places like that. The worst was a place where the only networking was wireless, and then only if you had a laptop that was on the "approved" list and if you were doing plain HTTP. Given that they were hosting a major meeting with senior budget holders from across a big project, things were *very* frosty. I think their security team got a serious earful from that…)

Comment: And when I say plain HTTP, I mean just that. No HTTPS. No alternate ports. No direct connections. I can't remember if they blocked POSTs. Someone paranoid (but not in a position to do a full body-cavity search of everyone leaving the building) seemed to be wanting to stop any chance of SEEKRITS!!! getting out, but instead just managed to totally prevent work being done. (By comparison, Mordac from the Dilbert strips is just plain reasonable and easy to work with.)

Answer (score 1):

See this question:

[Android game UDP / TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935424/android-game-udp-tcp/4935687)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really linked to Java.  UDP datagrams are not guaranteed to reach the destination, TCP datagrams are.  Consecutive UDP datagrams can also reach their destinations out of order.  For instance DNS is based on UDP because requests and responses just take one datagram.  If you need reliability and do not want to implement retries. TCP is your choice.  Nowadays, the computing overhead is minimal, so that I don't think there is much performance gain to expect from favouring UDP.

Comment: Strictly speaking TCP packets are not guaranteed to arrive.  The guarantees are that 1. if they don't, the sender's O/S will try again, 2. likewise, if they're corrupted, 3. if they do arrive it'll be in the right order

Comment: Agreed.  I should probably have stated things like this "If a connection is established, the they are reliably delivered" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My experience with UDP and TCP is like this:

- UDP is **significantly** faster. we're talking 2 orders of magnitude.
- On wired networks, UDP packet loss is less than 1%
- On wireless, UDP packet loss can easily reach 80%, and the physical distance to the router matters: you'll lose 20% of packets from a foot away and 50% from 20 feet away.

So UDP is good for non-essential stuff. For example, if 2 dudes are running around in your game, and Player A receives Player B's current coordinates and velocity over UDP every 100 millis, Player A can extrapolate for a while without going too far off. If on the other hand Player A has a full house, and Player B got a royal flush, the situation is different.

In my project, I used UDP as the primary communication scheme, with every receiver sending back a notification. If communication failed for longer than X though, I resorted to TCP.