# Should I use UDP or TCP for my Minecraft-style game?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, minecraft, multiplayer

I'm creating a 2D Minecraft style game, where the map is stored in a 2-dimensional int array.

You can place and destroy blocks and ai-controlled characters will walk around the map.
The game's made using xna/c#.
The problem is that I don't have much experience coding networked games.

Which protocol should I use? UDP, TCP? Or perhaps the Lindgren library? (which uses UDP + reliability)

Should I let the following things be done on the client, server or on both?

1. ai/pathfinding
2. collision detection

Also, is it good practice to send destroy and place-block messages to the server?
I guess that when the client starts, it first needs to download the map. And then changes to the map will be made in parallel to the maps on the clients and the one on the server...

Finally, should I broadcast the positions of the characters only when they change (tends towards TCP) or should I continually send them (tends towards UDP)?

Comment: TCP is slower, UDP is faster. Also TCP is guaranteed and UDP isn't. So based on what your priorities are, you should weigh the differences.

Comment: Do keep in mind that apart from the reliability issue discussed, UDP also poses NAT traversal issues. You would need to employ techniques like UDP punching etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel as if the thread below has some nice information that will be useful to you. Like AmitApollo said, in a nutshell UDP is faster, but less reliable. If all your information you're sending across this network is absolutely vital then TCP might be the best implementation. You could always try both and see what kinds of performance/latency hits you have. In general, most fast paced/realtime games I've read up on have used UDP.

[Android game UDP / TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935424/android-game-udp-tcp)

Comment: The thread was helpfull. The thing is, should i continually send the positions of the ai-characters, or only when there position changes?

Comment: Well if there position hasn't changed, why would you need to send there positions? Just have the client "pause" collision detection until you receive anouther packet on the new position.

Comment: You've got a good point there :)  But should the collision detection be done serverside or clientside? Because, if you only do it server-side, sending positions will be enough. If i take that approach, i might as well do the ai on the server. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Well it would be nice to keep players in sync by doing it serverside, and to prevent hacking. I've always been interested in the same question.

Comment: It's nice to just let the client be a dump terminal. Since there won't be that many updates necessary i think i'll go with the tcp approach. If that gets too slow, i'll try lidgren with reliability. And since the client is a dump terminal, we don't need any kind of negotiation between server and client to see which of the 2 holds the correct game data. Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: This link below may help with your collision detection question. I would explain it, but these guys do a much better job that I can, haha. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/should-collision-detection-be-done-server-side-or-cooperatively-between-client-s

Comment: Pressed enter too soon... As for AI, I suggest doing AI server-side for the reason noted above - much harder to hack. A lot of MMO's will actually have the client attempt to predict where the NPC's will go to improve smoothness for each client. And then confirm the actual action with the server. Here's a thread explaining this a little more http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15996/who-does-the-ai-calculations-in-an-mmo

Comment: Thanks for the Articles, they're very good. The multiplayer will be mainly for 2 to 4 players, so i think it's ok to let the server do the AI etc.

Comment: I'd like to add if you were only going to send the position when it has changed then you will need to do TCP. because if you use UDP and that position change packet doesn't make it then the server will assume the player hasn't moved. If your going to have attacking in your minecraft style game between players or server sided NPC's then it would be best to use UDP.

Comment: There will be fighting, but this will happen via a command to fight, not the actual fighting itself... rts-style. Can this be done via TCP or is it still recommended to do this kind of fighting with UDP.

Comment: You will normally want to use UDP in the case of fast realtime action based games or racers. It depends on the speed at which your user is going to expect the game to be played. I believe most RTS's are probably written using TCP. But I cannot confirm. I suggest testing TCP and if it's not working out then switch over to UDP and see if it helps :)

Comment: Ok then i'll first look into implementing TCP, thanks for all the answers :)

Comment: Not a problem! Good luck on your game! :)

Answer (score 2):

Everything should be verified by the server so that the game is not hackable or modifiable; either by modifying memory addresses or some other vulnerability.

Both AI/pathfinding and collision should be validated by the server however using TCP for both would cause congestion because of the handshake and window overhead. MMO's today use UDP packets with custom congestion control and handshakes. As a first version you should simply use a UDP packet - when packets are lost or dropped in transmission the game will simply `lag` and freeze until a UDP packet gets through. Subsequent versions of your game could implement a custom acknowledgment setup with UDP such that the character will pause until validated.

```
Client --    Movement request UDP    --> Server
Client: Character is frozen              Server: Validate coordinates on map
Client: <-- YES or NO to move request -- Server
Client: Move character based on response
```

This makes sure that every movement by the characters are valid. You will also need security keys or protocol security so that not just anyone can send coordinates to be validated.

You may think this design will lag your game but if properly designed it will be secure and free from client-side hacking. Remember to design your UDP packets to be as small as possible (size-wise).

Comment: This is incorrect: "MMO's today use UDP packets" -- both World of Warcraft and Guild Wars use TCP.